# Google script flextable span columns

Tags: google-apps-script, flextable

I am trying to make an input box which spans the 3 columns of the table. From looking online it seems like I need to use the

```
setStyleAttribute
```

but I am not sure and cannot decipher the documentation. I know from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/flex-table?hl=zh-tw#setStyleAttribute(String,String)) that

> A flexible table that creates cells on demand. It can be jagged (that is, each row can contain a different number of cells) and ***individual cells can be set to span multiple rows or columns***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hunch is correct, use setStyleAttribute to set the appropriate margin to a NEGATIVE value. if all the columns on your flextable are 40px wide, your control is in cell 0,0, and you want it to span across columns 1 & 2, you would use something like this:

```
app.getElementById('x').setStyleAttributes({'marginRight':'-80'});
```

see [here for some variations on the property assignments](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_margin.asp), though the method syntax needs to follow the format given in the Google documentation